# How to login in Fantasy Premier League using Ionic v1

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

Some APIs for fantasy are using authentification csrfToken so my question is,
How can I get authenticated information of fantasy premier league website. I am getting authentication failure ionic v1 angularjs.
how may i get sessionid , pl_profile and csrftoken

```
var data = {
        login:login,
        password:password,
        redirect_uri:'https://fantasy.premierleague.com',
        app:'plfpl-web'
      }
    $http({
      method:'POST',
      url:'https://users.premierleague.com/accounts/login/',
      data:data,
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8',
      }
```

Comment: add your token to your headers

Comment: do you mean Firebase plugin for cordova

Comment: no. add Token to your headers in your `$http({
headers: {
'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8',
youToken: 'your Token Value'
}
})`